# Can named pipes/FIFOs be used in a "cyclic" manner together with `tee`?

Tags: bash, fifo, tee

Why does the last line in this script gets stuck?

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'rm -f numbers' EXIT

mkfifo numbers

decrement() {
  while read -r number; do
    echo "debug: $number" >&2

    if (( number )); then
      echo $(( --number ))
    else
      break
    fi
  done
}

echo 10 > numbers &

# Works: prints the debug line
decrement < numbers >> numbers

# Works: prints an infinite stream of 10's
cat numbers | tee numbers

# Fails: prints "debug: 10" and then gets stuck
cat numbers | decrement | tee numbers
```

Below is the question as I originally wrote it, but it contains a lot of unnecessary details. However, I'm keeping it just in case someone is curious to know how I bumped into this. Here goes:

---

Is it possible to use named pipes/fifos in a cyclic way? Something like this:

```
line → fifo ←───────┐
         │          │
         ↓          ↑
         │          │
       curl ─────→ tee → stdout
```

Here's the problem I had to solve. I wanted to write a Bash utility to fetch all the tags of a Docker image using the Docker Hub API. The basic request is this:

```
declare -r repo=library%2Fubuntu # %2F is a URL-encoded forward slash
curl "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/$repo/tags/?page=1&page_size=100"
```

You'll notice that the response includes a link to the next page in case the total count of image tags is greater than the number of items requested per page (which has an upper limit of 100). Additionally, the `next` field is set to `null` when on the last page.

```json
{
  "count": 447,
  "next": "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library%2Fubuntu/tags/?page=2&page_size=1"
  "previous": null,
  "results": []
}
```

The problem looked recursive to me, which is what I attempted to do, and managed to solve it in the end by piping into a recursive call:

```bash
url-encode() {
  # A lazy trick to URL-encode strings using `jq`.
  printf '"%s"' "$1" | jq --raw-output '@uri'
}

fetch() {
  # The first line fed in to `fetch` is the URL we have to fetch
  read -r next_url

  # The rest of the stdin are the tag names we need to send to stdout
  cat

  # BASE CASE
  #
  # A `null` next link means we've just seen the last page, so we can return.
  #
  if [[ "$next_url" == "null" ]]; then return; fi

  # RECURSIVE CASE
  #
  #   1. Fetch the URL
  #   2. Extract the next link and the image tags using `jq`
  #   3. Pipe the result into a recursive call
  #
  echo "Fetching URL: $next_url" >&2
  curl --location --silent --show-error --fail "$next_url" \
    | jq --raw-output '.next, .results[].name' \
    | fetch
}

# We need a way to start off the recursive chain, which we do by sending
# a single line to `fetch` containing the URL of the first page we want
# to fetch.
first() {
  local -r repo=$(url-encode "$1")
  echo "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/$repo/tags/?page=1&page_size=100"
}

declare -r repo=$1

first "$repo" | fetch
```

Maybe this isn't ideal and I'm happy to receive suggestions on improving it, but for the purposes of this question I'm interested in whether the problem can be solved by using FIFO's. Probably FIFO's are not the best tool for the job, but I've just recently found out about them, so my mind tries to apply them even when they might not be ideal. In any case, here's what I've tried, but failed, to do when approaching the problem from a FIFO perspective.

In short, I've tried to reproduce the diagram posted at the beginning of the question:

```
first URL → fifo ←───────┐
              │          │
              ↓          ↑
              │          │
            curl ─────→ tee → stdout
```

```bash
mkfifo urls

# Remove FIFO on script exit.
trap 'rm -f urls' EXIT

fetch() {
  local url=$1

  # For each line we read from the FIFO, parse it as JSON and extract the
  # `next` field. If it's not null, we pass it to `curl` via `xargs`.
  #
  # The response is both sent to the `urls` FIFO and piped to another `jq`
  # call where we keep just what we're interested in — the tag names.
  #
  cat urls \
    | jq --raw-output '.next | select(. != null)' \
    | xargs curl --silent \
    | tee urls \
    | jq --raw-output '.results[].name' &
    # The pipeline above is successful in reading the first URL if we take
    # out the `tee urls` component of the pipeline. However, the pipeline
    # gets stuck if the `tee` component is present.

  # Start off the process of fetching by pushing a first URL to the FIFO.
  cat <<JSON > urls &
{"next": "$url"}
JSON

  # Both previous commands were started off asynchronously (hoping that
  # this will achieve the necessary concurrency on the `urls` FIFO), so
  # we need to wait on both of them to finish before returning.
  wait
}

fetch 'https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library%2Fubuntu/tags/?page=1&page_size=1'
```

Finally, here are my questions (and thank you for reading up until this point):

1. Why doesn't the above work?
2. How can the script be changed so that it works?

Thanks! And let me know if I should provide further details.

Answer (score 2):

Well, what you have here is a simple tail-call recursion, which basically reduces down to a loop.

```
next_url=

fetch() {
  curl "$1" 

  # do something with the data 

  next_url=$( something to produce the next URL or the empty string )
}

next_url=$first_url

# repeat calling `fetch` as long as there is an URL to use
while true; do
    fetch "$next_url"
    if [[ -z $next_url ]]; then break; fi
done
```

But yes, printing back to the pipe from the loop should also work. Try e.g. this in Bash:

```
mkfifo p
echo 42 > p & 
while read x; do
    echo $x; 
    if [[ $x == 0 ]]; then break; fi;
    echo $((RANDOM % 5)) >> p;
done < p
```

It should print `42`, then a random amount of numbers from 1 to 4, and then a zero.

This isn't really problematic in any way, since you're not even writing to the pipe from multiple processes at the same time.

Even if you have simultaneous writers, as long as each individual line is written with a single `write()` system call, the lines should not get split in the middle. That's what the usual tools do for at least short-ish strings. What "short-ish" means, depends on the system, but at least blocks of 512 bytes should be ok.

With broken tools or longer strings, you might get cases where a line is actually written in two parts, and another writer chances to get in the middle. E.g. the writes here:

```
proc #1          proc #2
write("good")
                 write("hello\n")
write("bye\n")
```

would show up to a reader as the two lines `goodhello` and `bye`, instead of `goodbye` and `hello`, as was intended.

---

With a pipe, you have to arrange it so that the reader doesn't need to see the end-of-file. E.g. by using `read` to always just read one line, or having more elaborate system of telling apart the boundaries of the items.

In your second script, I think it's the `xargs` call that tries to wait until EOF before running anything. That EOF never happens since the pipe is open for writing by `tee urls`. I wouldn't try building that in one single pipeline, really.

Comment: This answer misses a critical problem:  buffer size.  It might work in this one specific context because the problem is computationally just iterating through URLs.  On each iteration it will empty the buffer before writing a new URL and an URL is unlikely to exceed 65536 bytes - see [pipe capacity](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html). If this technique was applied to recursing a tree, or otherwise accumulating a backlog of things to process, it would eventually block on `write()`.  If writes were done in threads with `&` this would work (out of sequence)

Comment: @PhilipCouling, yep, you're right, I was only thinking of the situation in the Q, where each iteration only brings in one more, keeping the total amount of data at check. I'll see if I can edit, unless you're already half-way to an answer :)

Comment: Also I think your wording over atomicity is okay-ish but I think it should be clear that longer strings may be split.  I was reading [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node13.html) and cross referenced [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node13.html) the limit on linux is often 4096 bytes (defined as `PIPE_BUF` in `linux/limits.h`.  Otherwise nice answer.  I'd never noticed two processes are allowed to both write to the same pipe at once.

Comment: @ilkkachu thank you for your answer and sorry for the late reply. The recursive part is not the one that bothers me (I actually find it  easier to understand than the iterative one, but that's beside the point). I'm just trying to figure out why some combinations of pipes and `tee` doesn't seem to work. I've added a simplified example at the top of my question, based on the example you gave.